# How to decompress .zip files in c# without extracting to new location

Tags: c#, zip, compression

How can I decompress (.zip) files without extracting to a new location in the .net framework? Specifically, I'm trying to read a filename.csv.zip into a DataTable.
I'm aware of .extractToDirectory (which is within ZipArchive) but I just want to extract it into an object in c# and I would like to not create a new file.
Hoping to be able to do this w/o third party libraries, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: ZipArchiveEntry.Open() gives you a Stream object allowing you to read the decompressed data of a Zip archive entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some bugs because I never tested this, but here you go:

```
List<byte[]> urmom = new List<byte[]>();
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
         using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                urmom.Add(r.ReadToEnd(entry));
```

Basically you use the ZipArchive's openread class to iterate through each entry. At this point, you can use the streamreader to read each entry. From there you can create a file from the stream and even read the filename if you want to. My code doesn't do this, a bit of laziness on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a compressed stream might contain multiple files. To resolve this is required to iterate through all entries of zip file in order to retrieve them and treat separately.
The sample bellow converts a sequence of bytes in a list of string where each one is the context of the files included in zipped folder:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> DecompressToEntriesTextContext(byte[] input)
{
    var zipEntriesContext = new List<string>();
    using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(input))
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(compressedStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        foreach(var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            using (var memoryEntryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryEntryStream))
            {
               entryStream.CopyTo(memoryEntryStream);
               memoryEntryStream.Position = 0;
               zipEntriesContext.Add(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    return zipEntriesContext;
}
```